# Edit Text Editor SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, binding, text-editor

I am trying to edit the text of a binding value from another view. But text editor does not allow me to do so.

First I need to see the previous value of selectedNote.title in TextEditor and then I should be able to edit the title.

```
struct EditNotePageView: View {
    @Binding var selectedNote: CDNoteModel!
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(selectedNote.title!, text: $text)
    }
}
```

I also tried like this. I can see my selectedNote.title in the simulator but when I tap on it it does nothing.

```
 struct EditNotePageView: View {
    @Binding var selectedNote: CDNoteModel!
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text(selectedNote.title!)
            .onTapGesture {
                text = selectedNote.title!
                TextEditor(text: $text)
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZStack Text and textEditor solved the problem with a little pinch of .onAppear

```
  struct EditNotePageView: View {
    @Binding var selectedNote: CDNoteModel!
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text(selectedNote.title!)
                .onAppear {
                    text = selectedNote.title!
                }
            TextEditor(text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChange` property

```
struct EditNotePageView: View {
    @Binding var selectedNote: CDNoteModel!
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor("", text: $text)
        .onChange(of: text, perform: { value in
            selectedNote.title = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TextEditorm line gives an error of Ëxtran argument in call"for ""

Comment: I deleted "", but I do not see anything on TextEditor. It can not get selectedNote.title value and show it first

Answer (score -1):

you could try this:

```
struct EditNotePageView: View {
    @Binding var selectedNote: CDNoteModel
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $selectedNote.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: .title gives an error of "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'"

Comment: yes, too bad, your CDNoteModel.title should be a String otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: it is String. I uploaded an image

Comment: I can see my title in simulator like this. Text(selectedNote.title!)